# Microsoft Service Broker like queuing System in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008-r2, service-broker

We have implemented and used Service Broker in "SQL Server 2008R2". Now we are planning to migrate SQL Database to Oracle. 
**So do Oracle have queuing system like MSServiceBroker?**

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e11013/toc.htm ?